# pinting microsoft word review pane using C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I have just started using C#.  Is there way to print the entire review pane from a Microsoft Word file to a new text file using C# ?  I have only found visual basic code.

Comment: Anything that van be done in VB.net can be done in C# and vice-versa.

Comment: Try googling the topic more. Write some code to try it out. If you run into trouble, post the code you have and the specific issue you're having and we'll be happy to help.